# Riemann Integral Counterexample

Tags: real-analysis

It is known that if functions $f$ and $g$ are equal except on a null set, then $f$ is integrable if and only if $g$ is, and their integrals are equal.  Is there a counterexample to this for the Riemann integral?

Comment: when you say just integrable you mean Lebesgue integrable, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f=0$ and $g=1_{\Bbb Q}$ over any finite closed interval.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Certainly.

Answer (score 1):

For a (bounded) function $f$ to be Riemann integrable on some compact set, it is necessary and sufficient that the set of discontinuities of $f$ is a null set. So to generate a lot of counterexamples, choose your favorite continuous function, and change the values on $\mathbb{Q}$ to make it nowhere-continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Take any Riemann integrable $f$ and let $r_n$ be an enumeration of the rationals in the integration interval.
Define $g =f+ \sum_n n 1_{\{r_n\}}$. Since $g$ is unbounded, it is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Can you give a rigorous proof that $g$ is unbounded?

Comment: Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, it is bounded, say by $B$. Then $g(r_n) \ge n-B$.

Comment: Pick any closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$. My point is you have to prove that for any arbitrarily made enumeration of the rationals $r_1,\ldots$ there are $r_k\in [a,b]$ with $k$ arbitrily large. Can you do this?

Comment: Yes. $r_n$ is an enumeration of the rationals in $[a,b]$. All of the $r_n$ lie in $[a,b]$.

Comment: Even if they were an enumeration of all the rationals, we must have $r_n \in [a,b]$ infinitely often (otherwise the rationals in $[a,b]$ would be finite in number). So, choose $n$ and select the smallest $m \ge n$ such that $r_m \in [a,b]$, then $g(r_m) \ge n-B$, where $B$ is the bound on $f$.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't catch that it was an enumerations of the rationals in that interval.